# Creating artwork for display on 4K UHD video

Tags: screen-resolution, image-format

I was asked to create artwork for a 4K UHD video and was only given dimensions: 4096 x 2160. This is my first time ever designing for the screen, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

When creating a new file in Photoshop, I know I should input the exact dimensions above, but in the pixel/inch section, does it matter what number I put? Should I just work in 300 ppi as I usually do for print?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the question would be about Adobe’s bad UI here, it would actually be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

PPI stands for Pixel per Inch so a 4k resolution screen can have different PPI for different screens. It comes into play when the dimensions are in pixels.

As you have just one resolution to work with, PPI will not make much of a difference to your output.

Basically, select the resolution in **pixels** and forget about PPI in this case.